# error function (erf) with better precision

Tags: special-functions

Currently I'm using this C++ routine to approximate the error function

```
inline double erf(double x)
{
    ASSERT(x == x); // check for invalid number

    const double a1 =  0.254829592;
    const double a2 = -0.284496736;
    const double a3 =  1.421413741;
    const double a4 = -1.453152027;
    const double a5 =  1.061405429;
    const double p  =  0.3275911;

    double t = 1.0 / (1.0 + p * abs(x));
    double y = 1.0 - (((((a5 * t + a4) * t) + a3) * t + a2) * t + a1) * t * exp(-x*x);

    ASSERT(y > 0.0 && y < 1.0);
    return (x < 0.0 ? -y : y);
}
```

It is based on [this](http://www.johndcook.com/blog/2009/01/19/stand-alone-error-function-erf) post, but I was wondering how to improve its precision. I suspect I need to put in the constants with a better precision (16 digits) and I need more terms. Does anyone how to do this with e.g. a Maple sheet?

Comment: You should check out the terms "interpolation" and "richadson-extrapolation" maybe. The code you are using is basically a interpolation of $erf$ of degree 5 after dividing by $e^{-x^2}$ and substituting x with $\frac{1}{1+p|x|}$. Increasing the number of degree and maybe improving the sampling points positions makes the result more accurate.

Comment: A fine reference for this kind of approximations is the [Abramowitz and Stegun](http://people.math.sfu.ca/~cbm/aands/page_299.htm) with more formulas and the error terms.

Comment: @RaymondManzoni It's equation 7.1.26 in that book, however no explanation is given.

Comment: @demorge: from the formulation it should be a Taylor series of $(1-\mathrm{erf}(x))\,e^{x^2}$ (references are usually at the end of the chapter...). The error term is not so bad... Continued fractions (like 7.1.14) may give you as much precision as required.

Comment: @RaymondManzoni: Yes, but that yields 1 - 1.128*x - 0.7518*x^3 - 0.3008*x^5 + O(x^6), where to introduce t?

Comment: @demorge: sorry for the quick and incorrect answer (I had to leave...). The $(1-\mathrm{erf}(x))\,e^{x^2}$ polynomial is a (kind of) Chebyshev polynomial (it oscillates between $\pm \epsilon$). Some work is required to obtain such a polynomial ; this is explained in Hasting's 1955 book "Approximations for digital computers" (as indicated at the bottom of the linked page) (btw the polynomial on p.169 of the book is different with $p$ and the error term identical).

Comment: @RaymondManzoni: Thanks, I'm still curious and going to look up that book :)

Comment: Why not use the one that's built into C99?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The classic C code from Sun Microsystems.  It should provide exact results to within 2 ulps for IEEE doubles.  You can extract the different rational approximations and the different domains in which they're used if you want to convert to another language.

```
/*
Copyright (C) 1993 by Sun Microsystems, Inc. All rights reserved.
*
* Developed at SunPro, a Sun Microsystems, Inc. business.
* Permission to use, copy, modify, and distribute this
* software is freely granted, provided that this notice
* is preserved.
*/

double erf(double x);
double erfc(double x);
static const double tiny = 1e-300,
half= 5.00000000000000000000e-01, /* 0x3FE00000, 0x00000000 */
one = 1.00000000000000000000e+00, /* 0x3FF00000, 0x00000000 */
two = 2.00000000000000000000e+00, /* 0x40000000, 0x00000000 */
/* c = (float)0.84506291151 */
erx = 8.45062911510467529297e-01, /* 0x3FEB0AC1, 0x60000000 */
/*
* Coefficients for approximation to erf on [0,0.84375]
*/
efx = 1.28379167095512586316e-01, /* 0x3FC06EBA, 0x8214DB69 */
efx8= 1.02703333676410069053e+00, /* 0x3FF06EBA, 0x8214DB69 */
pp0 = 1.28379167095512558561e-01, /* 0x3FC06EBA, 0x8214DB68 */
pp1 = -3.25042107247001499370e-01, /* 0xBFD4CD7D, 0x691CB913 */
pp2 = -2.84817495755985104766e-02, /* 0xBF9D2A51, 0xDBD7194F */
pp3 = -5.77027029648944159157e-03, /* 0xBF77A291, 0x236668E4 */
pp4 = -2.37630166566501626084e-05, /* 0xBEF8EAD6, 0x120016AC */
qq1 = 3.97917223959155352819e-01, /* 0x3FD97779, 0xCDDADC09 */
qq2 = 6.50222499887672944485e-02, /* 0x3FB0A54C, 0x5536CEBA */
qq3 = 5.08130628187576562776e-03, /* 0x3F74D022, 0xC4D36B0F */
qq4 = 1.32494738004321644526e-04, /* 0x3F215DC9, 0x221C1A10 */
qq5 = -3.96022827877536812320e-06, /* 0xBED09C43, 0x42A26120 */
/*
* Coefficients for approximation to erf in [0.84375,1.25]
*/
pa0 = -2.36211856075265944077e-03, /* 0xBF6359B8, 0xBEF77538 */
pa1 = 4.14856118683748331666e-01, /* 0x3FDA8D00, 0xAD92B34D */
pa2 = -3.72207876035701323847e-01, /* 0xBFD7D240, 0xFBB8C3F1 */
pa3 = 3.18346619901161753674e-01, /* 0x3FD45FCA, 0x805120E4 */
pa4 = -1.10894694282396677476e-01, /* 0xBFBC6398, 0x3D3E28EC */
pa5 = 3.54783043256182359371e-02, /* 0x3FA22A36, 0x599795EB */
pa6 = -2.16637559486879084300e-03, /* 0xBF61BF38, 0x0A96073F */
qa1 = 1.06420880400844228286e-01, /* 0x3FBB3E66, 0x18EEE323 */
qa2 = 5.40397917702171048937e-01, /* 0x3FE14AF0, 0x92EB6F33 */
qa3 = 7.18286544141962662868e-02, /* 0x3FB2635C, 0xD99FE9A7 */
qa4 = 1.26171219808761642112e-01, /* 0x3FC02660, 0xE763351F */
qa5 = 1.36370839120290507362e-02, /* 0x3F8BEDC2, 0x6B51DD1C */
qa6 = 1.19844998467991074170e-02, /* 0x3F888B54, 0x5735151D */
/*
* Coefficients for approximation to erfc in [1.25,1/0.35]
*/
ra0 = -9.86494403484714822705e-03, /* 0xBF843412, 0x600D6435 */
ra1 = -6.93858572707181764372e-01, /* 0xBFE63416, 0xE4BA7360 */
ra2 = -1.05586262253232909814e+01, /* 0xC0251E04, 0x41B0E726 */
ra3 = -6.23753324503260060396e+01, /* 0xC04F300A, 0xE4CBA38D */
ra4 = -1.62396669462573470355e+02, /* 0xC0644CB1, 0x84282266 */
ra5 = -1.84605092906711035994e+02, /* 0xC067135C, 0xEBCCABB2 */
ra6 = -8.12874355063065934246e+01, /* 0xC0545265, 0x57E4D2F2 */
ra7 = -9.81432934416914548592e+00, /* 0xC023A0EF, 0xC69AC25C */
sa1 = 1.96512716674392571292e+01, /* 0x4033A6B9, 0xBD707687 */
sa2 = 1.37657754143519042600e+02, /* 0x4061350C, 0x526AE721 */
sa3 = 4.34565877475229228821e+02, /* 0x407B290D, 0xD58A1A71 */
sa4 = 6.45387271733267880336e+02, /* 0x40842B19, 0x21EC2868 */
sa5 = 4.29008140027567833386e+02, /* 0x407AD021, 0x57700314 */
sa6 = 1.08635005541779435134e+02, /* 0x405B28A3, 0xEE48AE2C */
sa7 = 6.57024977031928170135e+00, /* 0x401A47EF, 0x8E484A93 */
sa8 = -6.04244152148580987438e-02, /* 0xBFAEEFF2, 0xEE749A62 */
/*
* Coefficients for approximation to erfc in [1/.35,28]
*/
rb0 = -9.86494292470009928597e-03, /* 0xBF843412, 0x39E86F4A */
rb1 = -7.99283237680523006574e-01, /* 0xBFE993BA, 0x70C285DE */
rb2 = -1.77579549177547519889e+01, /* 0xC031C209, 0x555F995A */
rb3 = -1.60636384855821916062e+02, /* 0xC064145D, 0x43C5ED98 */
rb4 = -6.37566443368389627722e+02, /* 0xC083EC88, 0x1375F228 */
rb5 = -1.02509513161107724954e+03, /* 0xC0900461, 0x6A2E5992 */
rb6 = -4.83519191608651397019e+02, /* 0xC07E384E, 0x9BDC383F */
sb1 = 3.03380607434824582924e+01, /* 0x403E568B, 0x261D5190 */
sb2 = 3.25792512996573918826e+02, /* 0x40745CAE, 0x221B9F0A */
sb3 = 1.53672958608443695994e+03, /* 0x409802EB, 0x189D5118 */
sb4 = 3.19985821950859553908e+03, /* 0x40A8FFB7, 0x688C246A */
sb5 = 2.55305040643316442583e+03, /* 0x40A3F219, 0xCEDF3BE6 */
sb6 = 4.74528541206955367215e+02, /* 0x407DA874, 0xE79FE763 */
sb7 = -2.24409524465858183362e+01; /* 0xC03670E2, 0x42712D62 */

extern double exp(double);
extern double fabs(double);
double erf(double x)
{
int n0,hx,ix,i;
double R,S,P,Q,s,y,z,r;
n0 = ((*(int*)&one)>>29)^1;
hx = *(n0+(int*)&x);
ix = hx&0x7fffffff;
if(ix>=0x7ff00000) { /* erf(nan)=nan */
i = ((unsigned)hx>>31)<<1;
return (double)(1-i)+one/x; /* erf(+-inf)=+-1 */
}

if(ix < 0x3feb0000) { /* |x|<0.84375 */
if(ix < 0x3e300000) { /* |x|<2**-28 */
if (ix < 0x00800000)
return 0.125*(8.0*x+efx8*x); /*avoid underflow */
return x + efx*x;
}
z = x*x;
r = pp0+z*(pp1+z*(pp2+z*(pp3+z*pp4)));
s = one+z*(qq1+z*(qq2+z*(qq3+z*(qq4+z*qq5))));
y = r/s;
return x + x*y;
}
if(ix < 0x3ff40000) { /* 0.84375 <= |x| < 1.25 */
s = fabs(x)-one;
P = pa0+s*(pa1+s*(pa2+s*(pa3+s*(pa4+s*(pa5+s*pa6)))));
Q = one+s*(qa1+s*(qa2+s*(qa3+s*(qa4+s*(qa5+s*qa6)))));
if(hx>=0) return erx + P/Q; else return -erx - P/Q;
}
if (ix >= 0x40180000) { /* inf>|x|>=6 */
if(hx>=0) return one-tiny; else return tiny-one;
}
x = fabs(x);
s = one/(x*x);
if(ix< 0x4006DB6E) { /* |x| < 1/0.35 */
R=ra0+s*(ra1+s*(ra2+s*(ra3+s*(ra4+s*(
ra5+s*(ra6+s*ra7))))));
S=one+s*(sa1+s*(sa2+s*(sa3+s*(sa4+s*(
sa5+s*(sa6+s*(sa7+s*sa8)))))));
} else { /* |x| >= 1/0.35 */
R=rb0+s*(rb1+s*(rb2+s*(rb3+s*(rb4+s*(
rb5+s*rb6)))));
S=one+s*(sb1+s*(sb2+s*(sb3+s*(sb4+s*(
sb5+s*(sb6+s*sb7))))));
}
z = x;
*(1-n0+(int*)&z) = 0;
r = exp(-z*z-0.5625)*exp((z-x)*(z+x)+R/S);
if(hx>=0) return one-r/x; else return r/x-one;
}

double erfc(double x)
{
int n0,hx,ix;
double R,S,P,Q,s,y,z,r;
n0 = ((*(int*)&one)>>29)^1;
hx = *(n0+(int*)&x);
ix = hx&0x7fffffff;
if(ix>=0x7ff00000) { /* erfc(nan)=nan */
/* erfc(+-inf)=0,2 */
return (double)(((unsigned)hx>>31)<<1)+one/x;
}

if(ix < 0x3feb0000) { /* |x|<0.84375 */
if(ix < 0x3c700000) /* |x|<2**-56 */
return one-x;
z = x*x;
r = pp0+z*(pp1+z*(pp2+z*(pp3+z*pp4)));
s = one+z*(qq1+z*(qq2+z*(qq3+z*(qq4+z*qq5))));
y = r/s;
if(hx < 0x3fd00000) { /* x<1/4 */
return one-(x+x*y);
} else {
r = x*y;
r += (x-half);
return half - r ;
}
}
if(ix < 0x3ff40000) { /* 0.84375 <= |x| < 1.25 */
s = fabs(x)-one;
P = pa0+s*(pa1+s*(pa2+s*(pa3+s*(pa4+s*(pa5+s*pa6)))));
Q = one+s*(qa1+s*(qa2+s*(qa3+s*(qa4+s*(qa5+s*qa6)))));
if(hx>=0) {
z = one-erx; return z - P/Q;
} else {
z = erx+P/Q; return one+z;
}
}
if (ix < 0x403c0000) { /* |x|<28 */
x = fabs(x);
s = one/(x*x);
if(ix< 0x4006DB6D) { /* |x| < 1/.35 ~ 2.857143*/
R=ra0+s*(ra1+s*(ra2+s*(ra3+s*(ra4+s*(
ra5+s*(ra6+s*ra7))))));
S=one+s*(sa1+s*(sa2+s*(sa3+s*(sa4+s*(
sa5+s*(sa6+s*(sa7+s*sa8)))))));
} else { /* |x| >= 1/.35 ~ 2.857143 */
if(hx<0&&ix>=0x40180000) return two-tiny;/* x < -6 */
R=rb0+s*(rb1+s*(rb2+s*(rb3+s*(rb4+s*(
rb5+s*rb6)))));
S=one+s*(sb1+s*(sb2+s*(sb3+s*(sb4+s*(
sb5+s*(sb6+s*sb7))))));
}
z = x;
*(1-n0+(int*)&z) = 0;
r = exp(-z*z-0.5625)*
exp((z-x)*(z+x)+R/S);
if(hx>0) return r/x; else return two-r/x;
} else {
if(hx>0) return tiny*tiny; else return two-tiny;
}
}
```

Comment: I give up, I'm going with this one :)

Answer (score 2):

This was one of the top links I found when searching for the same thing in C#, so I'll post my translation of Sun's code here:

```
/// <summary>
/// Returns the value of the gaussian error function at <paramref name="x"/>.
/// </summary>
public static double Erf(double x)
{
    /*
    Copyright (C) 1993 by Sun Microsystems, Inc. All rights reserved.
    *
    * Developed at SunPro, a Sun Microsystems, Inc. business.
    * Permission to use, copy, modify, and distribute this
    * software is freely granted, provided that this notice
    * is preserved.
    */

    #region Constants

    const double tiny = 1e-300;
    const double erx = 8.45062911510467529297e-01;

    // Coefficients for approximation to erf on [0, 0.84375]
    const double efx  = 1.28379167095512586316e-01; /* 0x3FC06EBA; 0x8214DB69 */
    const double efx8 = 1.02703333676410069053e+00; /* 0x3FF06EBA; 0x8214DB69 */
    const double pp0 =  1.28379167095512558561e-01; /* 0x3FC06EBA; 0x8214DB68 */
    const double pp1 = -3.25042107247001499370e-01; /* 0xBFD4CD7D; 0x691CB913 */
    const double pp2 = -2.84817495755985104766e-02; /* 0xBF9D2A51; 0xDBD7194F */
    const double pp3 = -5.77027029648944159157e-03; /* 0xBF77A291; 0x236668E4 */
    const double pp4 = -2.37630166566501626084e-05; /* 0xBEF8EAD6; 0x120016AC */
    const double qq1 =  3.97917223959155352819e-01; /* 0x3FD97779; 0xCDDADC09 */
    const double qq2 =  6.50222499887672944485e-02; /* 0x3FB0A54C; 0x5536CEBA */
    const double qq3 =  5.08130628187576562776e-03; /* 0x3F74D022; 0xC4D36B0F */
    const double qq4 =  1.32494738004321644526e-04; /* 0x3F215DC9; 0x221C1A10 */
    const double qq5 = -3.96022827877536812320e-06; /* 0xBED09C43; 0x42A26120 */

    // Coefficients for approximation to erf in [0.84375, 1.25]
    const double pa0 = -2.36211856075265944077e-03; /* 0xBF6359B8; 0xBEF77538 */
    const double pa1 =  4.14856118683748331666e-01; /* 0x3FDA8D00; 0xAD92B34D */
    const double pa2 = -3.72207876035701323847e-01; /* 0xBFD7D240; 0xFBB8C3F1 */
    const double pa3 =  3.18346619901161753674e-01; /* 0x3FD45FCA; 0x805120E4 */
    const double pa4 = -1.10894694282396677476e-01; /* 0xBFBC6398; 0x3D3E28EC */
    const double pa5 =  3.54783043256182359371e-02; /* 0x3FA22A36; 0x599795EB */
    const double pa6 = -2.16637559486879084300e-03; /* 0xBF61BF38; 0x0A96073F */
    const double qa1 =  1.06420880400844228286e-01; /* 0x3FBB3E66; 0x18EEE323 */
    const double qa2 =  5.40397917702171048937e-01; /* 0x3FE14AF0; 0x92EB6F33 */
    const double qa3 =  7.18286544141962662868e-02; /* 0x3FB2635C; 0xD99FE9A7 */
    const double qa4 =  1.26171219808761642112e-01; /* 0x3FC02660; 0xE763351F */
    const double qa5 =  1.36370839120290507362e-02; /* 0x3F8BEDC2; 0x6B51DD1C */
    const double qa6 =  1.19844998467991074170e-02; /* 0x3F888B54; 0x5735151D */

    // Coefficients for approximation to erfc in [1.25, 1/0.35]
    const double ra0 = -9.86494403484714822705e-03; /* 0xBF843412; 0x600D6435 */
    const double ra1 = -6.93858572707181764372e-01; /* 0xBFE63416; 0xE4BA7360 */
    const double ra2 = -1.05586262253232909814e+01; /* 0xC0251E04; 0x41B0E726 */
    const double ra3 = -6.23753324503260060396e+01; /* 0xC04F300A; 0xE4CBA38D */
    const double ra4 = -1.62396669462573470355e+02; /* 0xC0644CB1; 0x84282266 */
    const double ra5 = -1.84605092906711035994e+02; /* 0xC067135C; 0xEBCCABB2 */
    const double ra6 = -8.12874355063065934246e+01; /* 0xC0545265; 0x57E4D2F2 */
    const double ra7 = -9.81432934416914548592e+00; /* 0xC023A0EF; 0xC69AC25C */
    const double sa1 =  1.96512716674392571292e+01; /* 0x4033A6B9; 0xBD707687 */
    const double sa2 =  1.37657754143519042600e+02; /* 0x4061350C; 0x526AE721 */
    const double sa3 =  4.34565877475229228821e+02; /* 0x407B290D; 0xD58A1A71 */
    const double sa4 =  6.45387271733267880336e+02; /* 0x40842B19; 0x21EC2868 */
    const double sa5 =  4.29008140027567833386e+02; /* 0x407AD021; 0x57700314 */
    const double sa6 =  1.08635005541779435134e+02; /* 0x405B28A3; 0xEE48AE2C */
    const double sa7 =  6.57024977031928170135e+00; /* 0x401A47EF; 0x8E484A93 */
    const double sa8 = -6.04244152148580987438e-02; /* 0xBFAEEFF2; 0xEE749A62 */

    // Coefficients for approximation to erfc in [1/0.35, 28]
    const double rb0 = -9.86494292470009928597e-03; /* 0xBF843412; 0x39E86F4A */
    const double rb1 = -7.99283237680523006574e-01; /* 0xBFE993BA; 0x70C285DE */
    const double rb2 = -1.77579549177547519889e+01; /* 0xC031C209; 0x555F995A */
    const double rb3 = -1.60636384855821916062e+02; /* 0xC064145D; 0x43C5ED98 */
    const double rb4 = -6.37566443368389627722e+02; /* 0xC083EC88; 0x1375F228 */
    const double rb5 = -1.02509513161107724954e+03; /* 0xC0900461; 0x6A2E5992 */
    const double rb6 = -4.83519191608651397019e+02; /* 0xC07E384E; 0x9BDC383F */
    const double sb1 =  3.03380607434824582924e+01; /* 0x403E568B; 0x261D5190 */
    const double sb2 =  3.25792512996573918826e+02; /* 0x40745CAE; 0x221B9F0A */
    const double sb3 =  1.53672958608443695994e+03; /* 0x409802EB; 0x189D5118 */
    const double sb4 =  3.19985821950859553908e+03; /* 0x40A8FFB7; 0x688C246A */
    const double sb5 =  2.55305040643316442583e+03; /* 0x40A3F219; 0xCEDF3BE6 */
    const double sb6 =  4.74528541206955367215e+02; /* 0x407DA874; 0xE79FE763 */
    const double sb7 = -2.24409524465858183362e+01; /* 0xC03670E2; 0x42712D62 */

    #endregion

    if (double.IsNaN(x))
        return double.NaN;

    if (double.IsNegativeInfinity(x))
        return -1.0;

    if (double.IsPositiveInfinity(x))
        return 1.0;

    int n0, hx, ix;
    double R, S, P, Q, s, y, z, r;
    unsafe
    {
        double one = 1.0;
        n0 = ((*(int*)&one) >> 29) ^ 1;
        hx = *(n0 + (int*)&x);
    }
    ix = hx & 0x7FFFFFFF;

    if (ix < 0x3FEB0000) // |x| < 0.84375
    {
        if (ix < 0x3E300000) // |x| < 2**-28
        {
            if (ix < 0x00800000)
                return 0.125 * (8.0 * x + efx8 * x); // avoid underflow
            return x + efx * x;
        }
        z = x * x;
        r = pp0 + z * (pp1 + z * (pp2 + z * (pp3 + z * pp4)));
        s = 1.0 + z * (qq1 + z * (qq2 + z * (qq3 + z * (qq4 + z * qq5))));
        y = r / s;
        return x + x * y;
    }
    if (ix < 0x3FF40000) // 0.84375 <= |x| < 1.25
    {
        s = Math.Abs(x) - 1.0;
        P = pa0 + s * (pa1 + s * (pa2 + s * (pa3 + s * (pa4 + s * (pa5 + s * pa6)))));
        Q = 1.0 + s * (qa1 + s * (qa2 + s * (qa3 + s * (qa4 + s * (qa5 + s * qa6)))));
        if (hx >= 0)
            return erx + P / Q;
        else
            return -erx - P / Q;
    }
    if (ix >= 0x40180000) // inf > |x| >= 6
    {
        if (hx >= 0)
            return 1.0 - tiny;
        else
            return tiny - 1.0;
    }
    x = Math.Abs(x);
    s = 1.0 / (x * x);
    if (ix < 0x4006DB6E) // |x| < 1/0.35
    {
        R = ra0 + s * (ra1 + s * (ra2 + s * (ra3 + s * (ra4 + s * (ra5 + s * (ra6 + s * ra7))))));
        S = 1.0 + s * (sa1 + s * (sa2 + s * (sa3 + s * (sa4 + s * (sa5 + s * (sa6 + s * (sa7 + s * sa8)))))));
    }
    else // |x| >= 1/0.35
    {
        R = rb0 + s * (rb1 + s * (rb2 + s * (rb3 + s * (rb4 + s * (rb5 + s * rb6)))));
        S = 1.0 + s * (sb1 + s * (sb2 + s * (sb3 + s * (sb4 + s * (sb5 + s * (sb6 + s * sb7))))));
    }
    z = x;
    unsafe { *(1 - n0 + (int*)&z) = 0; }
    r = Math.Exp(-z * z - 0.5625) * Math.Exp((z - x) * (z + x) + R / S);
    if (hx >= 0)
        return 1.0 - r / x;
    else
        return r / x - 1.0;
}

/// <summary>
/// Returns the value of the complementary error function at <paramref name="x"/>.
/// </summary>
public static double Erfc(double x)
{
    /*
    Copyright (C) 1993 by Sun Microsystems, Inc. All rights reserved.
    *
    * Developed at SunPro, a Sun Microsystems, Inc. business.
    * Permission to use, copy, modify, and distribute this
    * software is freely granted, provided that this notice
    * is preserved.
    */

    #region Constants

    const double tiny = 1e-300;
    const double erx = 8.45062911510467529297e-01;

    // Coefficients for approximation to erf on [0, 0.84375]
    const double efx  = 1.28379167095512586316e-01; /* 0x3FC06EBA; 0x8214DB69 */
    const double efx8 = 1.02703333676410069053e+00; /* 0x3FF06EBA; 0x8214DB69 */
    const double pp0 =  1.28379167095512558561e-01; /* 0x3FC06EBA; 0x8214DB68 */
    const double pp1 = -3.25042107247001499370e-01; /* 0xBFD4CD7D; 0x691CB913 */
    const double pp2 = -2.84817495755985104766e-02; /* 0xBF9D2A51; 0xDBD7194F */
    const double pp3 = -5.77027029648944159157e-03; /* 0xBF77A291; 0x236668E4 */
    const double pp4 = -2.37630166566501626084e-05; /* 0xBEF8EAD6; 0x120016AC */
    const double qq1 =  3.97917223959155352819e-01; /* 0x3FD97779; 0xCDDADC09 */
    const double qq2 =  6.50222499887672944485e-02; /* 0x3FB0A54C; 0x5536CEBA */
    const double qq3 =  5.08130628187576562776e-03; /* 0x3F74D022; 0xC4D36B0F */
    const double qq4 =  1.32494738004321644526e-04; /* 0x3F215DC9; 0x221C1A10 */
    const double qq5 = -3.96022827877536812320e-06; /* 0xBED09C43; 0x42A26120 */

    // Coefficients for approximation to erf in [0.84375, 1.25]
    const double pa0 = -2.36211856075265944077e-03; /* 0xBF6359B8; 0xBEF77538 */
    const double pa1 =  4.14856118683748331666e-01; /* 0x3FDA8D00; 0xAD92B34D */
    const double pa2 = -3.72207876035701323847e-01; /* 0xBFD7D240; 0xFBB8C3F1 */
    const double pa3 =  3.18346619901161753674e-01; /* 0x3FD45FCA; 0x805120E4 */
    const double pa4 = -1.10894694282396677476e-01; /* 0xBFBC6398; 0x3D3E28EC */
    const double pa5 =  3.54783043256182359371e-02; /* 0x3FA22A36; 0x599795EB */
    const double pa6 = -2.16637559486879084300e-03; /* 0xBF61BF38; 0x0A96073F */
    const double qa1 =  1.06420880400844228286e-01; /* 0x3FBB3E66; 0x18EEE323 */
    const double qa2 =  5.40397917702171048937e-01; /* 0x3FE14AF0; 0x92EB6F33 */
    const double qa3 =  7.18286544141962662868e-02; /* 0x3FB2635C; 0xD99FE9A7 */
    const double qa4 =  1.26171219808761642112e-01; /* 0x3FC02660; 0xE763351F */
    const double qa5 =  1.36370839120290507362e-02; /* 0x3F8BEDC2; 0x6B51DD1C */
    const double qa6 =  1.19844998467991074170e-02; /* 0x3F888B54; 0x5735151D */

    // Coefficients for approximation to erfc in [1.25, 1/0.35]
    const double ra0 = -9.86494403484714822705e-03; /* 0xBF843412; 0x600D6435 */
    const double ra1 = -6.93858572707181764372e-01; /* 0xBFE63416; 0xE4BA7360 */
    const double ra2 = -1.05586262253232909814e+01; /* 0xC0251E04; 0x41B0E726 */
    const double ra3 = -6.23753324503260060396e+01; /* 0xC04F300A; 0xE4CBA38D */
    const double ra4 = -1.62396669462573470355e+02; /* 0xC0644CB1; 0x84282266 */
    const double ra5 = -1.84605092906711035994e+02; /* 0xC067135C; 0xEBCCABB2 */
    const double ra6 = -8.12874355063065934246e+01; /* 0xC0545265; 0x57E4D2F2 */
    const double ra7 = -9.81432934416914548592e+00; /* 0xC023A0EF; 0xC69AC25C */
    const double sa1 =  1.96512716674392571292e+01; /* 0x4033A6B9; 0xBD707687 */
    const double sa2 =  1.37657754143519042600e+02; /* 0x4061350C; 0x526AE721 */
    const double sa3 =  4.34565877475229228821e+02; /* 0x407B290D; 0xD58A1A71 */
    const double sa4 =  6.45387271733267880336e+02; /* 0x40842B19; 0x21EC2868 */
    const double sa5 =  4.29008140027567833386e+02; /* 0x407AD021; 0x57700314 */
    const double sa6 =  1.08635005541779435134e+02; /* 0x405B28A3; 0xEE48AE2C */
    const double sa7 =  6.57024977031928170135e+00; /* 0x401A47EF; 0x8E484A93 */
    const double sa8 = -6.04244152148580987438e-02; /* 0xBFAEEFF2; 0xEE749A62 */

    // Coefficients for approximation to erfc in [1/0.35, 28]
    const double rb0 = -9.86494292470009928597e-03; /* 0xBF843412; 0x39E86F4A */
    const double rb1 = -7.99283237680523006574e-01; /* 0xBFE993BA; 0x70C285DE */
    const double rb2 = -1.77579549177547519889e+01; /* 0xC031C209; 0x555F995A */
    const double rb3 = -1.60636384855821916062e+02; /* 0xC064145D; 0x43C5ED98 */
    const double rb4 = -6.37566443368389627722e+02; /* 0xC083EC88; 0x1375F228 */
    const double rb5 = -1.02509513161107724954e+03; /* 0xC0900461; 0x6A2E5992 */
    const double rb6 = -4.83519191608651397019e+02; /* 0xC07E384E; 0x9BDC383F */
    const double sb1 =  3.03380607434824582924e+01; /* 0x403E568B; 0x261D5190 */
    const double sb2 =  3.25792512996573918826e+02; /* 0x40745CAE; 0x221B9F0A */
    const double sb3 =  1.53672958608443695994e+03; /* 0x409802EB; 0x189D5118 */
    const double sb4 =  3.19985821950859553908e+03; /* 0x40A8FFB7; 0x688C246A */
    const double sb5 =  2.55305040643316442583e+03; /* 0x40A3F219; 0xCEDF3BE6 */
    const double sb6 =  4.74528541206955367215e+02; /* 0x407DA874; 0xE79FE763 */
    const double sb7 = -2.24409524465858183362e+01; /* 0xC03670E2; 0x42712D62 */

    #endregion

    if (double.IsNaN(x))
        return double.NaN;

    if (double.IsNegativeInfinity(x))
        return 2.0;

    if (double.IsPositiveInfinity(x))
        return 0.0;

    int n0, hx, ix;
    double R, S, P, Q, s, y, z, r;
    unsafe
    {
        double one = 1.0;
        n0 = ((*(int*)&one) >> 29) ^ 1;
        hx = *(n0 + (int*)&x);
    }
    ix = hx & 0x7FFFFFFF;

    if (ix < 0x3FEB0000) // |x| < 0.84375
    {
        if (ix < 0x3C700000) // |x| < 2**-56
            return 1.0 - x;
        z = x * x;
        r = pp0 + z * (pp1 + z * (pp2 + z * (pp3 + z * pp4)));
        s = 1.0 + z * (qq1 + z * (qq2 + z * (qq3 + z * (qq4 + z * qq5))));
        y = r / s;
        if (hx < 0x3FD00000) // x < 1/4
            return 1.0 - (x + x * y);
        else
        {
            r = x * y;
            r += (x - 0.5);
            return 0.5 - r;
        }
    }
    if (ix < 0x3FF40000) // 0.84375 <= |x| < 1.25
    {
        s = Math.Abs(x) - 1.0;
        P = pa0 + s * (pa1 + s * (pa2 + s * (pa3 + s * (pa4 + s * (pa5 + s * pa6)))));
        Q = 1.0 + s * (qa1 + s * (qa2 + s * (qa3 + s * (qa4 + s * (qa5 + s * qa6)))));
        if (hx >= 0)
        {
            z = 1.0 - erx;
            return z - P / Q;
        }
        else
        {
            z = erx + P / Q;
            return 1.0 + z;
        }
    }
    if (ix < 0x403C0000) // |x| < 28
    {
        x = Math.Abs(x);
        s = 1.0 / (x * x);
        if (ix < 0x4006DB6D) // |x| < 1/.35 ~ 2.857143
        {
            R = ra0 + s * (ra1 + s * (ra2 + s * (ra3 + s * (ra4 + s * (ra5 + s * (ra6 + s * ra7))))));
            S = 1.0 + s * (sa1 + s * (sa2 + s * (sa3 + s * (sa4 + s * (sa5 + s * (sa6 + s * (sa7 + s * sa8)))))));
        }
        else // |x| >= 1/.35 ~ 2.857143
        {
            if (hx < 0 && ix >= 0x40180000)
                return 2.0 - tiny; // x < -6
            R = rb0 + s * (rb1 + s * (rb2 + s * (rb3 + s * (rb4 + s * (rb5 + s * rb6)))));
            S = 1.0 + s * (sb1 + s * (sb2 + s * (sb3 + s * (sb4 + s * (sb5 + s * (sb6 + s * sb7))))));
        }
        z = x;
        unsafe { *(1 - n0 + (int*)&z) = 0; }
        r = Math.Exp(-z * z - 0.5625) *
        Math.Exp((z - x) * (z + x) + R / S);
        if (hx > 0)
            return r / x;
        else
            return 2.0 - r / x;
    }
    else
    {
        if (hx > 0)
            return tiny * tiny;
        else
            return 2.0 - tiny;
    }
}
```